# How to create a custom set of coordinates based on two points in Unity?

Tags: unity, transformation, coordinates, linear-algebra

As the title says, I am having problems finding a way to create a new set of local coordinates based on two points. Here is an example:

[image]

Consider that the two gameObjects are not one parent of another, therefore I cannot use something like `transform.localPosition`, furthermore I tried using `transform.TransformPoint()`, however the latter works only if if I want to create it with respect to a single point.
I think it is a silly question, yet I am not finding a way to solve it, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, I understand you want the second point to be on the Y+ axis of the local coordinate system you're building, and the local Z+ axis to correspond to the world Z+ axis. We can get this like so:

```
Matrix4x4 GetCoordinateSystemFromPoints(
              Vector3 origin,
              Vector3 pointOnYPlusAxis)
{    
    return Matrix4x4.TRS(
             origin,
             Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, pointOnZPlusAxis - origin),
             Vector3.One
    );
}
```

You can transform a point from this local space to world space with:

```
var worldPoint = matrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(localPoint);
```

And transform from world space to local space with:

```
Matrix4x4 inverse;
Matrix4x4.Inverse3DAffine(matrix, ref inverse);

var localPoint = inverse.MultiplyPoint3x4(localPoint);
```

The downside of this is that it's somewhat more expensive to invert.

You could instead define your own `CoordinateSystem` struct that includes both the forward and inverse matrix, or an origin & quaternion pair, so you can transform both into and out of this coordinate system frequently without repeatedly computing a matrix inverse, something like this:

```
public struct CoordinateSystem {
    // 7 floats instead of 12-16 for a 3x4 or 4x4 matrix.
    public readonly Quaternion orientation;
    public readonly Vector3 origin;

    public CoordinateSystem(Vector3 origin, Vector3 pointOnYPlusAxis) {
        this.origin = origin;
        this.orientation = Quaternion.LookRotation(
                              Vector3.forward, pointOnYPlusAxis - origin);
    }

    public Vector3 TransformVector(Vector3 vector) {
        return orientation * vector;
    }    

    public Vector3 InverseTransformVector(Vector3 vector) {
        // Quaternion inverse is cheaper than a matrix inverse: just 3 negations.
        // The compiler may be able to combine this with the multiplication below.
        var inverse = Quaternion.Inverse(orientation);
        return inverse * vector;
    }

    public Vector3 TransformPoint(Vector3 point) {
        return origin + TransformVector(point);
    }

    public Vector3 InverseTransformPoint(Vector3 point) {
        return InverseTransformVector(point - origin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Quick question: I did not mention that I wanted to use it on a 2D plane, putting the second point on the y-axis, my bad. I just have a quick 2 questions: 1) isn't Vector3.up related to the y+ direction (0, 1, 0)? 2) Is it true to say that if I want to do the same on the 2D plane working on the y-axis, I should just change the LookRotation line?

Comment: Actually, third question: once I have the transformation matrix, I should multiply a given vector in order to transform it according to the new reference system, however, working with a 3x1 vector, I cannot multiply it by a 4x4 matrix, so how do I apply the transformation? (Man I should really look back at my old algebra notes :0 )

Comment: Please edit your question to ensure it contains a complete definition of the coordinate transformation you want, to avoid getting answers that do something different from what you want. "I cannot multiply it by a 4x4 matrix" - why not? [The documented API provides methods to do this just fine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.html).